# Typescript onclick event type for React Link / href - Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am just trying to add a simple click event in TS.

### func

```
  const displayNewClaim = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

### TS error

```
Type '{ children: string; to: string; styles: "button"; onClick: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322

    81 |           <input type="file" name="fileupload" /> <button>Upload CSV</button>
    82 |         </form>
  > 83 |         <Link to="/new-claim" styles="button" onClick={displayNewClaim}>
       |                                               ^
    84 |           New claim
    85 |         </Link>
    86 |       </Header>
```

Comment: Which version of @types/react-router-dom have you installed? The [current version](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/46c3dc08d8efb51686530f24cea216ab8c17d8be/types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts#L69) does not match your error

Comment: Interesting, thanks Jonas, I will see if I can update it. Humm its the latest version 5.2.0. I will clean node_modules

Comment: Also what does the import look like? `import { Link } from "react-router-dom";` ?

Comment: Ye, exactly: import { Link as RLink } from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: So this [does clearly work](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js), maybe the Types are mixed up ... not sure why it says `React.RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>`  Instead of `Parameters<HtmlAnchorElement>` ...

Comment: You are correct @JonasWilms removing the node_modules and doing a fresh install fixed it up! Frustrating, but thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Here you can do something like

```
 <Link styles="button" onClick={(e) => displayNewClaim(e)}>New claim</Link>
```

function

import

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
```

function

```
const displayNewClaim = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  navigate('/new-claim')
  };
```

Comment: gatsby? Thank you though, however the error here isn't due to the navigation libiary as ai can

Answer (score -1):

dont listen, to them answers. you just have to make sure to have them types installed

```
npm i -D @types/react
```

the problem is bcuz `HTMLElement` do not have `onClick` eventHandler

```js
const anchorTag = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
}
const buttonTag = (e:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

you just have to make sure to use html tags that have it **HTMLAnchorElement**, **HTMLButtonElement**